# Turn off REST Authorization in Fedora-Commons 3.8.1

Tags: fedora-commons

I'm trying to make a REST call to fedora-commons 3.8.1 and I continually get "401 Unauthorized" errors. I googled it and found that I need to make sure:

```
<param name="ENFORCE-MODE" value="permit-all-requests"/>
```

Is set in the Authorization module, which I did. Seems like an easy enough fix. I restarted my server and still get the same error.

Comment: Okay I've also played around with the files in the REPOSITORY-POLICIES-DIRECTORY specified in the fcfg file. I've removed individual policies that look like they might cause this and also removed all policies entirely and still get the same 401: Unauthorized error.

Comment: Also tried to uncomment the "serviceSecurityDescription" lines from beSecurity.xml in the conf directory (no idea what this file does). Still same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a spring configuration in the fedora/config area that seems to be overriding enforce-mode (at least in this version).

Fixed this by modifying the fedora/server/config/spring/web/web.properties file:

```
#Spring override properties
#Fri Jan 23 08:32:41 GMT-05:00 2015
security.ssl.api.management=ANY_CHANNEL
security.auth.filters=AuthFilterJAAS
#security.fesl.authN.jaas.apia.enabled=true
security.fesl.authN.jaas.apia.enabled=false
fedora.port=8080
security.fesl.authZ.enabled=false
#fedora.port.secure=8080
fedora.port.secure=8443
security.ssl.api.default=ANY_CHANNEL
security.ssl.api.access=ANY_CHANNEL
```